# Ingest application created logs GCP logging to display application errors and info logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

I have an application that is written into python3 and deployed on GCP. My application generates some logs[INFO, ERROR]. But now I want to see those logs into the GCP logging dashboard or stack driver.

Comment: How is the application deployed onto GCP - compute engine, app engine, cloud functions, firebase functions, GKE, cloud run...

Comment: Depending on your deploy, it automatically stores all Standard I/O (stdout, stderr...) directly to the Stackdriver Logging. How is your application being deployed?

Answer (score 2):

if you are running your application on GCP VM then [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) would be the best option.

The Ops Agent serves as the main tool for gathering telemetry data from your Compute Engine instances. It consolidates the collection of logs, metrics, and traces into one streamlined process. Utilizing Fluent Bit for logs, it enables high-throughput logging, while for metrics and traces, it leverages the OpenTelemetry Collector.

it offers the Enhanced performance in contrast to the legacy Logging Agent, featuring:

- High throughput, leveraging multi-core architecture efficiently.
- Optimal resource management, including memory and CPU.

Additionally, I found other resources online. Please find them [1](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-write-logs-to-google-cloud-logging-in-python-46e7b514c60b),[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI4iG2GIZMA)